# A workaround with templates for changing a type

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, type-traits

Considering this delegate class:

```
template <class DELEGATECLASS, class METHODPTRSPEC>
class CLDelegate
{
public:
    CLDelegate();
    CLDelegate( DELEGATECLASS* instancePtr, METHODPTRSPEC methodPtr );
    CLDelegate( const CLDelegate& rhs );

    DELEGATECLASS* pInstance_;
    METHODPTRSPEC pMethod_;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
template <class DELEGATECLASS, class METHODPTRSPEC>
CLDelegate<DELEGATECLASS, METHODPTRSPEC>::CLDelegate()
    : pInstance_( nullptr )
    , pMethod_( nullptr )
{}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
template <class DELEGATECLASS, class METHODPTRSPEC>
CLDelegate<DELEGATECLASS, METHODPTRSPEC>::CLDelegate( DELEGATECLASS*
        instancePtr, METHODPTRSPEC methodPtr )
    : pInstance_( instancePtr )
    , pMethod_( methodPtr )
{}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
template <class DELEGATECLASS, class METHODPTRSPEC>
CLDelegate<DELEGATECLASS, METHODPTRSPEC>::CLDelegate( const CLDelegate& rhs )
    : pInstance_( rhs.pInstance_ )
    , pMethod_( rhs.pMethod_ )
{}
```

I would like to use this delegate within another class, but I would have to have template parameters for the whole class,  which I do not want, like this:

```
template<class DELEGATECLASS, class METHODPTR>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    IOVFUCam();
    ~IOVFUCam();

    // Data Members
private:
    ...
    const CLDelegate<DELEGATECLASS, METHODPTR>& del_;
};
```

Since I do not want to use template parameters on the whole class I wonder if it is possible to have a dummy delegate in my class and change its type (at compile time ?) :

```
struct EmptyType
{};

class SomeClass
{
public:
    template<class DELEGATECLASS, class METHODPTR>
    IOVFUCam( CLDelegate<DELEGATECLASS, METHODPTR> del )
     : del_(del)
    {};

    ~IOVFUCam();

    // Data Members
private:
    ...
    const CLDelegate<EmptyType, EmptyType>& del_;
};


FrameHandler handler;
CLDelegate<FrameHandler,
           void(FrameHandler::*)( IOBuffer::Ptr )>
           del( &handler, &FrameHandler::ProcessImage );
SomeClass obj( del );
```

I rapidly read something that Alexandrescu wrote about TypeTraits, and I wonder if this could be applied to my issue, or another technique ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: probably you didn't tell some details about your `CLDelegate`, but why not to use just `std::bind` (and a container of nulary `std::function<void()>` in `SomeClass`)

Comment: The method used in bind must be static is that right ?

Comment: s/must/may/. It is not mandatory. `bind` can bind all callable entities

Comment: Ok, could you show me / explain a bit more how to use it in my code for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen std::allocator? It has a 'rebind' type that allows an std::allocator to give you an std::allocator at compile time.

```
template <class DELEGATECLASS, class METHODPTRSPEC>
class CLDelegate
{
public:
    template<class D, class M>
    struct rebind {
        typedef CLDelegate<D, M> type;
    };

    CLDelegate();
    CLDelegate( DELEGATECLASS* instancePtr, METHODPTRSPEC methodPtr );
    CLDelegate( const CLDelegate& rhs );

    DELEGATECLASS* pInstance_;
    METHODPTRSPEC pMethod_;
};
```

This way if you have a CLDelegate type already you can use the following code to get a different CLDelegate type.

```
typename MyDelType::rebind<NewDel, NewSpec>::type
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: If you could tell us more about what you are trying to do we might be able to direct you along a better path. I'm rather uncertain of the issue at hand now and I'm not sure you are going about this correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I was too exited about this little trick that I forgot to explain my problems properly. I solved everything except one little thing that remains. I am currently writing a gist to show you the code.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/athanase/6206698) is the gist. My problem is that the member `del_` is not a dynamic object. So the `del_` in the constructor is actually a local object. So I either have to put the `rebind` code in the initialization list, or make `del_` a dynamic object... what is your opinion ?

Comment: Arf, I think this is not helpfull since I realized that assigning a `typename EmptyDel::rebind` to a `EmptyDel *` is forbidden :(